# correct way to define array in python

Tags: python, c++, arrays, simulation

my simulator (c++) is using python as for binding. 
in my c++, i define array as follows

this is my variable declaration (in header)

```
 Ptr<Name> m_names [2];
```

this is my function declaration (in header)

```
void SetName (unsigned which, Ptr<Name> name);
void SetName (unsigned which, const Name &name);
```

in source file

```
void Interest::SetName (unsigned which, Ptr<Name> name)
{
    if (which < 2)
    {
        m_names[which] = name;
    }
}

void Interest::SetName (unsigned which, const Name &name)
{
    if (which < 2)
    {
        m_names[which] = Create<Name> (name);
    }
}
```

The way I call this is like this (in my main file):

```
interest->SetName (0, nameWithSequence);
interest->SetName (1, nameWithNextSequence);
```

as a result it give error like this

```
src/ndnSIM/bindings/ns3module.cc: In function ‘PyObject*   _wrap_PyNs3NdnData_SetName__0(PyNs3NdnData*, PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject**)’:
src/ndnSIM/bindings/ns3module.cc:8418:62: error: no matching function for call to  ‘ns3::ndn::Data::SetName(ns3::Ptr<ns3::ndn::Name>)’
src/ndnSIM/bindings/ns3module.cc:8418:62: note: candidates are:
./ns3/ndn-data.h:60:3: note: void ns3::ndn::Data::SetName(unsigned int,     ns3::Ptr<ns3::ndn::Name>)
./ns3/ndn-data.h:60:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

this is the original python code for SetName

```
PyObject *
_wrap_PyNs3NdnData_SetName__0(PyNs3NdnData *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs,   PyObject **return_exception)
{
    PyObject *py_retval;
    PyNs3NdnName *name;
    ns3::ndn::Name *name_ptr;
    const char *keywords[] = {"name", NULL};

    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwargs, (char *) "O!", (char **) keywords,   &PyNs3NdnName_Type, &name)) {
        {
            PyObject *exc_type, *traceback;
            PyErr_Fetch(&exc_type, return_exception, &traceback);
            Py_XDECREF(exc_type);
            Py_XDECREF(traceback);
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    name_ptr = (name ? name->obj : NULL);
    self->obj->SetName(ns3::Ptr< ns3::ndn::Name  > (name_ptr));
    Py_INCREF(Py_None);
    py_retval = Py_None;
    return py_retval;
}
```

Im new in python, need help base on code given to set array definition in python. thanks

Comment: Why do you have two versions of `SetName()`, one that takes its argument by copy and one that takes it by const reference? And why are these two actually defined differently? One version should suffice (and then you wouldn't get the error).

Comment: The `self->obj->SetName` takes two parameters so it should be correct, you sure this is the source code that the error is referring to? The error is `src/ndnSIM/bindings/ns3module.cc:8418:62`: is `self->obj->SetName` line 8418 of ns3module.cc?

Answer (score 1):

Based on http://ndnsim.net/getting-started.html, ndnsim uses [pybindgen](https://code.google.com/p/pybindgen/) to generate the python bindings. Based on http://packages.python.org/PyBindGen/tutorial.html#work-flows there are 3 ways that your bindings could be generated, you have to find which one ndn uses. If you had to write a python script then verify that

```
mod.add_function('SetName', None, ['int', '...'])
```

has two parameters not 1 (as per 
http://packages.python.org/PyBindGen/tutorial.html#code-generation-script). But my guess is that you or ndnsim run (py)gccxml on your header file. If that is the case, then the problem is likely a bug in pybindgen since t is reading your header file directly it is not something you do wrong.

You should verify that your .h and cpp compile and build properly outside of ndnsim (comment out any code that is ndnspecific) and run in a main.cpp, just to make sure it is really a pybindgen issue.

Consider posting to http://www.lists.cs.ucla.edu/mailman/listinfo/ndnsim.